# Is ActionDescriptor.Id unique to a request in ActionExecutingContext and ActionExecutedContext in IActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Given this code (using .Net Core 2.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v2.0.2):

```
public class MyFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var mayOrMayNotBeUniquePerRequest = context.ActionDescriptor.Id;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var mayOrMayNotBeUniquePerRequest = context.ActionDescriptor.Id;
    }
}
```

My question is, are those Ids "per-request"? Or "per-action"? I've looked here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.0 - and it's not clear.

For clarification, the filter is used as per this code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
   config.Filters.Add(new RequestLoggingFilter());
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation says "Gets an id which uniquely identifies the action.". From where did you get the idea that it would change per request?

Comment: Don't be rude. Consider this an unofficial warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "per-action". I tested it against two different requests and the ID was the same.

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up since I had the same question, if you look at the source on GitHub, it is a new value each action:

```
public class ActionDescriptor
{
    public ActionDescriptor()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        // ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an id which uniquely identifies the action.
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; }
```

My testing reveals that the Id is generated when the action is invoked and the value remains constant until your site stops/starts or recycles. The value would then be different. So, the Id would be the same for each request and is not unique.

Id: 75c077ac-5402-444d-8a1b-73bdfc30f8ef
Id: 75c077ac-5402-444d-8a1b-73bdfc30f8ef
Recycle
Id: ef19524e-4fd3-4386-b15d-e5f3d65beb26

Reference: [AspNetCore/ActionDescriptor.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Abstractions/src/Abstractions/ActionDescriptor.cs)